# Determining redirected URL in Python

Tags: python, parsing, redirect

I made a little parser using HTMLparser and I would like to know where a link is redirected. I don't know how to explain this, so please look this example:

On my page I have a link on the source: `http://www.myweb.com?out=147`, which redirects to `http://www.mylink.com`. I can parse `http://www.myweb.com?out=147` without any problems, but I don't know how to get `http://www.mylink.com`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2) ([`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) in Python 3) and its [`HTTPRedirectHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#httpredirecthandler-objects) in order to find out where a URL will redirect you. Here's a function that does that:

```
import urllib2

def get_redirected_url(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler)
    request = opener.open(url)
    return request.url

print get_redirected_url("http://google.com/")
# prints "http://www.google.com/"
```

Comment: One slight gotcha with this is that if a redirect redirects to another redirect, you'll only get the last redirect. For example, say you have a t.co (Twitter's URL shortener) link, which actually refers to a bit.ly link, which refers to some real website, then you'll get the "real" website instead of the bit.ly link. This may or may not be what one wants.

Comment: And in case someone else looking for the answer to that sees this question, the Requests library (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) makes this not only possible but also trivial.

Answer (score 3):

You can not get hold of the redirection URL through parsing the HTML source code. 
Redirections are triggered by the server and NOT by the client. You need to perform a HTTP request to the related URL and check the HTTP response of the server - in particular for the HTTP status code 304 (Redirection) and the new URL.